# Parameter is not valid. error when using System.Drawing.ImageConverter or MemoryStream

Tags: c#, sql, data-conversion

Trying to retrieve image from my Database but always getting "Parameter is not valid." error. I tried to use couple methods and none of them worked for me.

My table: [image]

Data in my table[image]

I wrote a small python code to get images from URL that listed in image Column and put them in bImage.

```
import sqlite3

import requests

conn = sqlite3.connect(f'Laptops.db')
c = conn.cursor()
cc = conn.cursor()
s = requests.Session()


def getImage(imgLink):
    headers = {...}
    r = s.get(imgLink, headers=headers, stream=True)

    if r.status_code == 200:
        imgBinary = r.content
        return imgBinary


def executeScriptsFromFile():
    for test in c.execute("SELECT image FROM products"):
        if str(test[0]) != "None":
            imgBinary = getImage(str(test[0]))
            print("d")
            excuteCommand(imgBinary, test[0])
    conn.commit()


def excuteCommand(imgBinary, test):
    cc.execute('''UPDATE products SET bImage = ? WHERE image = ?''', (imgBinary, test))
```

---

```
            SqlDataAdapter myAdapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(new SqlCommand("select bImage from dbo.Laptops", conn));
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            myAdapter1.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                
                byte[] imgBytes = ((byte[])row["bImage"]);
                
                ImageConverter imageConverter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
                Image image = imageConverter.ConvertFrom(imgBytes) as Image; <--ERROR //System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.'

                return image;
```

Comment: What is the Type of the `bImage` Column (in your db)? How did that image get into your database? -- What is that `bImage` string up there? Is it meant to show the content of the Column in the DataTable? That's not a byte array. -- Why are you filling a DataTable? Is it used for something else, not shown here?

Comment: You should change the Type of `bImage` to `VARBINARY(MAX)` and show the procedure that's storing the images.

Comment: What are we looking at here? You have python code that stores the content of a Stream to a SQLite db, which is supposed to store the data in a `BLOB` Column, but then you have C# code that queries SQL Server - apparently, given the objects used  and the Table structure, which shows an `IMAGE` Type Column and other Types that don't belong to a SQLite db